# Injecting a view model dependency with a non-default constructor

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, inversion-of-control, ninject

In windows phone application I have a custom user control that is databound to an instance of a `BookProgressInfo` class.

```
<deusControls:BookProgressBar BookProgressValue="{Binding BookProgressInfo}" Width="430" />
```

Whenever `BookProgressInfo` changes, a

```
static void BookProgressValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var bookProgressBar = (BookProgressBar)sender;

            var progressInfo = (BookProgressInfo) e.NewValue;

            if(progressInfo != null && progressInfo.Id != 0) 
                bookProgressBar.ProgressBarListBox.DataContext = new BookProgressBarViewModel(progressInfo, bookProgressBar.Width);
        }
```

gets called. I am setting a new DataContext on a `bookProgressBar.ProgressBarListBox` every time a bound property for an entire control changes.

I used to have only one BookProgressBarViewModel, so everything worked fine as implemented in an above snippet.

Now I want to support different `BookProgressBarViewModel`s, so I have introduced an interface - IBookProgressBarViewModel.

As you can see, the constructor for `BookProgressBarViewModel` has parameters.

I am using Ninject kernel as an IoC container and it get's initiated in App.xaml.

How can I create an instance of a corresponding `IBookProgressBarViewModel` defined in IoC container within the `BookProgressValueChanged`?

UPDATE: I have altered an architecture so that I don't need to call a parametrized view model constructor from within the dependency property changed event handler. Still I would like to hear your suggestions on this question.

Comment: I think Ninject allows you to register and object which required parameters. Or is it something else which is a problem? I think I might be missing the point here.

Comment: @Vitalij, in `NinjectModule` one can pass parameters into a constructor of the dependency, or even pass a delegate to a method to compute these parameters. But in my case the values are not known until the view is required. There is no way to generate these instances up front. But now I think I can have a class `viewModelParametersProvider`, and call it's routines from an initialization method in Ninject module the moment the dependency is required.

Answer (score 0):

Why not still use a IoC container and then make your values Lazy Loaded? Then your IoC can inject your dependencies and create those instances and until you know its values then you just update it the property when needed.